# Search button not displaying specific data on the table

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have 4 rows of data in the table. I managed to display all the data using PDO select query. I also have a search button for displaying specific data from my database. It's working but instead of filtering and displaying the specific data I have searched, it just added on the table.
Here is my code for search button:

```
if(isset($_POST['search_btn']))
{
$row = null;    
if(empty($_POST['InvNumbTxt']))
{
echo '<h3>*Please input invoice number!</h3>';
}
else
{
$invtxt = $_POST['InvNumbTxt'];
$dbh=db_connect();         
$sql1="SELECT * FROM invalid_invoice WHERE Invoice_Number='".$invtxt."'";
$stmt1=$dbh->prepare($sql1);    
$stmt1->execute();

while( $row2 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>


<td><?php echo $row2['Issue_Type']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['Creation_Date']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['Site']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['Vendor_Name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['Invoice_Date']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['Invoice_Number']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['Part_Number']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['PO']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['RR']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['Currency']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['Invoice_Amount']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['Issues']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['PersoninCharge']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['PIC_Comments']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['Status']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row2['ID']; ?></td>

<?php
}  
?>
</tr> 
<?php  
$dbh = null;
 }
}
?>
```

Here is the code for displaying the data on the table:

```
$invtxt = $_POST['InvNumbTxt'];
$dbh=db_connect();         
$sql="SELECT * FROM invalid_invoice";
$stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);  
$stmt->execute();

echo "<form name='update' method='POST'><tr class=output2>";

while($row =$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

echo "<td>".$row['Issue_Type']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Creation_Date']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Site']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Vendor_Name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Invoice_Date']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Invoice_Number']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Part_Number']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['PO']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['RR']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Currency']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Invoice_Amount']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Issues']."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='pic' value='".$row['PersoninCharge']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='comt' value='".$row['PIC_Comments']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='stat' value='".$row['Status']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='save_btn' value='&diams; SAVE &diams;' style='font-size:1em;'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='idtxt' value='".$row['ID']."'/></td>";
echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</form>";

$dbh=null;
<tr class=output2>
<?php
```

Comment: you've to include the code where you're fetching all the rows

Comment: I already added that part on my question for your reference

Comment: Can you give an exemple of rows displayed with no search, and those with your search ?

Comment: By default, all data are displayed on the table. Then I have a search button for searching specific data. Whenever I search an invoice_number, the data is added on the table making it new row for the table. I want to display a specific data on the table based on what I searched

Comment: Are you getting any errors??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a check to display all records only when `serach_btn` is not set. Something like:

```
$invtxt = $_POST['InvNumbTxt'];
$dbh=db_connect();         
$sql="SELECT * FROM invalid_invoice";
$stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);  
$stmt->execute();

echo "<form name='update' method='POST'><tr class=output2>";

if(!isset($_POST['search_btn'])) {
while($row =$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

echo "<td>".$row['Issue_Type']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Creation_Date']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Site']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Vendor_Name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Invoice_Date']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Invoice_Number']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Part_Number']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['PO']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['RR']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Currency']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Invoice_Amount']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Issues']."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='pic' value='".$row['PersoninCharge']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='comt' value='".$row['PIC_Comments']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='stat' value='".$row['Status']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='save_btn' value='&diams; SAVE &diams;' style='font-size:1em;'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='idtxt' value='".$row['ID']."'/></td>";
echo "</tr>"; 
} 
}
echo "</form>";

$dbh=null;
<tr class=output2>
```